# Streaming pipeline on Apache Flink runner (parallelism and grouping of tasks written using Apache Beam)

Tags: parallel-processing, operators, apache-flink, apache-beam

I am already  having a stream pipeline written in Apache beam. Earlier I was running the same in Google Dataflow and it used to run like a charm. Now due to changing business needs I need to run it using flink runner.

Currently in use beam *version is 2.38.0*, *Flink version is 1.14.5*. I validated this and found this is supported and valid combination of versions.

The pipeline code which is written using Apache Beam sdk and it uses multiple **ParDo** and **PTransforms**. The pipeline is somewhat complicated in nature as it involves lot of interim operations (catered via these ParDo & PTransforms) between source and sink.The source in my case is Azure service bus topic which I am reading using JmsTopicIO reads. Until here all works fine i.e. stream of data enters in to the pipeline and getting processed normally. The problem occurs when load testing is performed. I see many operator going in to back pressure and eventually not able to read & process msgs from topic. Though the **CPU and memory** usage remains well under control of **Job & Task manager**.

**Actual issue/problem/question**: While troubleshooting this performance issues I observed that Flink is chaining and grouping these ParDo's and PTranforms (by itself) in to operators. With my implementation I see that many heavy processing tasks are getting combined in to same operator. This is causing slow processing of all such operators. Also the parallelism I have set (20 for now) is at pipeline level which mean each operator is running with 20 parallelism.
`flinkOptions.setParallelism(20);`

**Question 1.** Using apache beam sdk or any flink configuration is there any way I can control or manage the chaining and grouping of these ParDo/PTransforms in to operators (through code or config)?. So I should be able to uniformly distribute the load myself.

**Question 2.** With implementation using Apache Beam, how I can mention or set the parallelism to each operator (not to complete pipeline) based on the load on them?. This way I will be able to better allocate the resources to heavy computing operators (set of tasks).

Please suggest answers to above questions. Also if any other pointer can be given to me to work up on for flink performance improvements in my deployment. Just for reference please note my pipeline [image: looks like].

Comment: Can someone please help me with the above 2 queries.